# How to implement an Dynamic Action Selection for Reinforcement Learning Agents

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I have Discrete action space where the agent can lower or decrease a certain value. However I do NOT want that the agent changes the value by a fixed amount like "increase value by 2" but that the agent dynamically chooses the amount by which it wants to increase or decrease a certain value. How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

By how much can your agent lower/increase the value?

For instance if it can change it by +5/-5, then you could output probabilities for a categorical distribution, where the support of your distribution are integers between [-5, 5] (e.g. via softmax on the last layer) such that the agent can "dynamically" choose that value.

However, if the magnitude of the change is higher (-1000/+1000), I'd recommend having your agent output continuous values and you'd round them yourself. If the magnitude of the change is large it probably won't matter much if when rounding you do a -1 or a +1 on the target value.